# How to upload ignored files to github repository

Tags: git, github, repository, gitignore, git-clone

In my local repository, I have 8 files

[image]

But in I have specified to ignore `.mat` files in `.gitignore`. So when pushing the repository on github, the ignored files are not added.
But I want anyone who clones my repository later, have the `.mat` files and photos as examples of the data which work with the program.

I can upload the files but that way the user who clone the repository later won't download those files when cloning.

I also can modify the `.gitignore` file and commit adding `.mat` files to include them on my github repository.

But is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in I have specified to ignore .mat files in .gitignore. So when pushing the repository on github, the ignored files are not added.

The ignored files are not added because you didn't add them :) not because of `.gitignore`.

> I can upload the files but that way the user who clone the repository later won't download those files when cloning.

This is wrong. If these files are in the repository they will be cloned. So one way to go is to `git add --force` () them and commit.

`.gitignore` would change the output of "Untracked files" when running `git status` - if a file or file type is there then it wouldn't be shown in "Untracked files" list. But you can still add and commit it.

You should only modify `.gitignore` if you want any `.mat` files to *be* shown from now on in "Untracked files" list. But if you just want to add a few specific ones to your repository and that's it then you shouldn't modify it.

See [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more info.

Comment: But looking at the [history](https://github.com/SepidehAbadpour/Photogrammetry-2D-Conversions/commit/dd6dda49e1e2039f0a6fe24d6713cb6c97b6df11) I've first added and committed `.mat` files last night and then have [added](https://github.com/SepidehAbadpour/Photogrammetry-2D-Conversions/commit/6b47c187d844bce18f227ad37683cd484d2dcec9) the `.gitignore` file and later [modified](https://github.com/SepidehAbadpour/Photogrammetry-2D-Conversions/commit/dae58603e2e99db9e04d5f1d94cabc544a0ef3fe) it to ignore th

Comment: @SepidehAbadppour - ok, so what are you asking?

Comment: i mean i have added them but they were not uploaded when pushing

Comment: According to your repo history, you added the `mat` files (commit dd6dda4) and only later you modified `.gitignore` it to include `mat` files (commit dae5860). After you added them they were pushed as you can see them right now in your repo. This `.gitignore` modification didn't affect these `mat` files because they're already pushed and exist in the repo. So again, what is not working as expected for you now?